# Get entities (geo:point) ordered by distance

Tags: fiware-orion

(Moved from https://ask.fiware.org/question/637/get-entities-geopoint-ordered-by-distance)

Hi all, I would like to retrieve from orion context broker (v2) a list of entities with geo:point attribute ordered by distance from a defined point. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `orderBy=geo:distance` parameter could be used to do that, for example:

```
GET /v2/entities?georel=near;maxDistance:1000&geometry=point&coords=-40.4,-3.5&orderBy=geo:distance
```